# Windows talking or sending commands to linux

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, ssh

In my particular use case I want my PC to be able to send commands to a Linux machine ,to execute a script on it . Is there a way to do this (via a network or some other method ) I am using Windows 7 on my PC and Ubuntu for the Linux Machine.

Comment: Do you know about SSH?  Happy to provide an answer based on SSH if that sounds like what you need.

Comment: Sure , yes please that would be great

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is almost always done with SSH.

You need to have a setup where:

- Windows is an SSH Client.
- Linux is an SSH Server.

Once you connect Windows (as a client) to the Linux server, and login, you'll have a terminal (shell/bash depending on your config), and you can execute any command just as if you are on the Linux machine itself.

### Windows SSH Client:

Use Putty:  http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html

All you need is to get the IP address of the Linux SSH server.

### Linux SSH Server:

Ubuntu normally comes with openssh-server pre-installed.
To make sure, run

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

Once installed, the configuration of the server (how you can login, port, etc.), can be found here:

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Again, with Ubuntu, the default configuration should be fine, and allows login with username and password, on port 22.  Therefore, you shouldn't need to change anything.

Finally, you need to make sure this Linux server is connected on a network that is accessible to the Windows Client, and that the SSH port (default 22) is not blocked.
For example, the machine can be either, on the same home/work network (connected on the same router/switch, in the same network infrastructure), or somehow accessible on the public Internet.
Once you have this server's IP address, you can connect to it from any (Windows or other) SSH client, and execute any command remotely... and even upload/download files (using "scp", putty version is called "pscp").

Comment: And if you install Xmig, you can have a Xserver on your Windows desktop, where you can see the windows from your Lunix pc, as **actually separated windows** on your Windows desktop.

Answer (score 2):

Use [PuTTY](http://www.putty.org) to connect in SSH to the Linux computer.

Docs for command line usage: http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.67/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline

You'll especially want to look for the `-m` option.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all your suggestions ,I figured out the way the way to do it and would like to share it for other peoples benefit

**Step 1:** After installing Putty on my windows system I used this command to install the ssh server on ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

**Step 2:** After the installation I used this command on the command line window of my PC to control the Ubuntu machine

```
plink.exe -ssh user@host -pw password -m c:\path\command.txt
```

where command.txt consists of the lists of task I wanted to execute on Ubuntu.

***Note :*** For users who are using a virtual box for you to connect to Ubuntu via putty you must set the Network settings of your virtual machine from NAT to Bridged Network otherwise connecting via ssh cannot be possible .

Comment: If you're using a VirtualBox Virtual Machine, you can also use the Host-only Network, to get a connection directly to the host.  That way, you'll not need a Bridged connection to a real network.